# The use of modulo 2 in state representation after CNOT

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-circuit

The following circuit with a CNOT gate has the following effect on a computational basis state $|a, b\rangle$, where all additions are done modulo 2.

[image]
[image]

Why is the state of the second qubit changed to $a\oplus b$ after CNOT is applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of the CNOT gate. The definition has been chosen this way, because

$$ 0 \oplus b = b \\ 1 \oplus b = \neg b $$

where $\neg$ denotes bit-flip and $\oplus$ denotes addition modulo $2$. In other words, $a\oplus b$ does nothing to $b$ if $a=0$ and it flips $b$ if $a=1$. This is what one would expect a controlled-NOT gate to do.

Comment: Hi! Would you mind explaing why $1 \oplus b = \neg b$? I totally understand everything else in your answer! Thank you!

Comment: Just check all (i.e. both) possibilities: $1\oplus 0 = 1 = \neg 0$ and $1\oplus 1 = 0 = \neg 1$.